# Arduino Uno Rev3 Internal Quartz

Tags: arduino-uno, oscillator-clock

I'm using an Arduino Uno Rev3 Board and need to send a trigger signal at a certain frequency (20-50Hz).
This trigger signal should be as accurate as possible (+/- 0.01 ms).
The Arduino site states that the arduino uno has a 16MHz Quartz Crystal, but I'm measuring a frequency accuracy of about 0.35% (which would be typical for a ceramic resonator) instead of what i could expect from a quartz (0.001%).
I'm using the micros() function to measure time.
Am I doing something wrong? How is my frequency so inaccurate?

Thanks for your help! :)

[image]

Edit: Indeed when I have a look at the schematics, I see the ceramic resonator (Blue circle). However, there seems to be another 16 MHz part (red circle). could that be a quartz oscillator?

Comment: Can you please provide the measurement code by editing your question?

Comment: I don't know why they say it has a quartz crystal - it doesn't - it has a ceramic resonator.  This one: https://uk.farnell.com/murata/cstce16m0v53-r0/resonator-ceramic-16mhz-smd/dp/2443265

Comment: @Majenko omg are you sure? My whole project relies on this accuracy. Why would they make a false statement on the official website? Is there even an arduino board (alternative) with a quartz crystal?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. That is the part from the schematic. I have emailed the webmaster to try and get the error corrected on the product page. There are plenty of other better boards with crystals - more powerful boards generally, such as Teensy, chipKIT, etc.

Comment: alright. Thank you :)

Comment: All the boards I make with 328P, 1284P, 2560, all use quartz crystals.  0.01mS = 10uS, yes? You can get down to 4uS with micros(), but you have to write code that runs within loop() and doesn't have jitter introduced by loop() background code.  For example, I needed to load 45 shift registers with 8 MHz SPI; to do so I had to disable interrupts and write 45 discrete SPI.transfer lines (spdr = array[0]; 15 no-ops, then spdr = array[1]); 15 no-ops, etc.)  If interrupts were on, I could see (on logic analyzer) that the micros() interrupt would disrupt the timing flow. loop() made is worse.

Comment: The Arduino Uno Rev3 has an ATmega328P.
@Majenko as far as I can interpret the schematic, there are two components, the one you sent (ceramic resonator) and another one, possibly the quartz? I try to attach the image

Comment: @MarayJay The Uno R3 has a quartz crystal to run the ATMega16U2, not the ATMega328P. It's the one for the ATMega328P that you care about.  Quartz is required for USB for the accuracy, but not for UART since it's more forgiving.

Comment: Ok so there is no possibility to get the accuracy of the quartz to control an output pin with this board?

Comment: @MarayJay No, I'm afraid not.

Comment: @MarayJay If you are good with soldering, there is no reason why you can't replace the resonator on the board with a 16 MHz crystal and two ceramic capacitors (22 uF). Something like this: https://images.app.goo.gl/x5KSXfUf9y1Q9K6e6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATMega328P chip is, indeed, clocked by a ceramic resonator. The website is misleading in stating that it has a crystal (I have emailed the webmaster to try and get this corrected, though I don't hold out much hope).

The 16MHz crystal in the schematics is part of the USB interface circuitry and has nothing to do with the timing of your running code. It is purely used to clock the ATMega16U2 chip which provides USB connectivity (USB requires a higher accuracy for stable communication).

There are other boards available with better crystals - most often boards that have native USB connections, such as the Arduino Due or Leonardo, or any of the myriad of boards by other manufacturers, like Teensy or chipKIT.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!
I struggle finding an alternative that provides the following specs:
- 5V Output (I need a 5V signal)
- Quartz crystal
- RS-232 communication possible
- USB connection to connect computer

Would you have a suggestion?

Comment: @MarayJay The Arduino Leonardo may be your best bet.

Comment: do i understand this right: The leonardo just has one quartz oscillator, because there is no second processor for the usb communication? And you are 100% sure that this is a quartz oscillator, right? I don't trust the arduino page anymore, so i trust you. (you're saving my day btw)

Comment: @MarayJay The Leonardo has a direct ("native") USB connection. It comprises the functionality of both the chips on the Uno in one. USB requires the accuracy of a quartz crystal. You can also use the Arduino Micro if you want a smaller footprint. Same chip, just a smaller board.

Comment: Thank you so much :)